# Why is an inclusion map from an open subset smooth?

Tags: differential-geometry, submanifold

If $B$ is a manifold and $A\subseteq B$ is a regular submanifold of $B$, then the inclusion map $i:A\to B$ is an embedding and thus smooth.

If $B$ is a manifold, and $A\subseteq B$ is an open subset of $B$, then how do we justify that the inclusion map $i:A\to B$ smooth **without using that $i$ is an embedding** (in the [sense of differential geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding#Differential_topology); 'embedding' in the [sense of elementary topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding#General_topology) is within scope) **or $A$ is a regular submanifold**? Also, do not use germs or tangent space please.

Thanks in advance!

---

Here's my answer:

Let $i: A \to B$ be inclusion for $A$ an open subset of $B$. To show $i$ is smooth, we must show $i$ is continuous (known from elementary topology) and that for all $a \in A$, there are charts $(C,\gamma)$ about $i(a)=a \in B$ and $(D,\delta)$ about $a \in A$ for which $\gamma \circ i \circ \delta^{-1}: \gamma(i^{-1}(C) \cap D) = \gamma(C \cap D)$ $\to \gamma(C)$ is smooth

For any $a \in A$, choose $C=D=A$ and $\gamma=\delta=\text{id}_A$ identity function on $A$. Then $\gamma \circ i \circ \delta^{-1}: \gamma(i^{-1}(C) \cap D) = \gamma(C \cap D)$ $\to \gamma(C)$ becomes $i: A \to A$. We know that the inclusion map, with its range restricted to its image which happens to be its domain, becomes the identity map on its domain. Since the identity map on any manifold is smooth (I think), $i: A \to A$ is smooth. This satisfies the definition for $i: A \to B$ to be smooth.

Comment: This is trivial. By definition, the inclusion map is always an embedding with the subspace topology, and with the induced smooth structure it is obviously smooth.

Comment: @MattSamuel I said without using embedding, but perhaps you are referring to a embedding of topological manifolds instead of smooth manifolds?

Comment: What I mean is that the inclusion map from $A$ is trivially an embedding.

Comment: If $A$ is an open subset.

Comment: @MattSamuel Do you mean embedding in the sense of [elementary topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding#General_topology) (a map that becomes a homeomorphism when its range is restricted to its image) instead of in the sense of [differential geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding#Differential_topology) (injective immersion whose image in the subspace topology is homeomorphic to its domain) ?

Comment: How do you define the smooth structure on an open subset? If you look at the definition you'll see it's automatically a smooth embedding for an open subset.

Comment: @MattSamuel Okay, I had a second look at the definition, and I think I just proved it. I don't think this is obvious for a beginner however.

Comment: Great. Then you can answer your question with the proof.

Comment: @MattSamuel Thanks. I tried answering it, but I realised I actually don't know why identity on a manifold is smooth, if it is. Is it?

Comment: @MattSamuel Does some diffeomorphism $f$ exist on any smooth manifold $B$ by definition of the differentiable structure on $B$?

Comment: I think my proof is more of an intuitive one. You really should prove the it is a diffeomorphism directly. But if it isn't, the manifold isn't diffeomorphic to any manifold, even itself, and diffeomorphism wouldn't be an equivalence relation.

Comment: @MattSamuel is my answer here relevant maybe? [When is an inclusion map smooth?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3078112/when-is-an-inclusion-map-smooth)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a smooth structure $\{u_a, \phi_a\}$, it induces a natural smooth structure in the subspace topology. Overload the notation for simplicity

$$
\phi_a \circ i \circ \phi^{-1}_b = \phi_a \circ \phi^{-1}_b
$$

which must be smooth by the definition of a smooth structure, since we require that all transition functions be smooth.

The fact that it's open just guarantees that it remains locally homeomorphic to balls in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Comment: is my answer here relevant maybe? [When is an inclusion map smooth?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3078112/when-is-an-inclusion-map-smooth)